# SOLR: how to use wildcard and question mark in field value

Tags: indexing, solr, wildcard

I've read a lot of pages for last few days, but can find any samples for configuring field analizer for following situation:
- field value may contain both ? and *:

- abcdef1;
- ab?de?2;
- abc?e*.

- query may contain it too:

- "ab??e*" and "ab*"- as result should resolve all documents;
- "ab1*" - only second.

Is it possible to configure SOLR in that way?

Comment: Please reformat the question body. It's very hard to follow.

Comment: Ok, now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may need to create your field type and apply the same to your field.

Your field type should consist of such tokenizer and filter which will generate the tokens.

You can read more on the use tokenizer and filter on the solr wiki page.

You can also have different analyzer for indexing and query.

This also depends on your requirement.

I would suggest you to try below field type.

You can add the below field type in your schema.xml.
Use the "partial_search" fieldType for your field(s) where you want to perform the partial/wildcard search.

Once you are done with schema.xml changes, you need to do the restart the server ans re-index the data.

```
<fieldType name="partial_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: It's not allowed to use more than one tokenizer, so it should be like following:`<fieldType name="partial_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>`

Comment: Anyway your approach is good and cover a lot of variants, except following: field=`ab?de?2` and query=`ab1*`. And another one: field=`ab*` and query=`ab1234`.

Comment: I think about ab?de?2 is not possible to achieve... As you won't be able to create any such tokens...still you can try from your end...what I suggest is using ngram you could able to achieve partial or wildcard search...when you have a text like word 'abhijit'...then with above field type you will create tokens like ab,abh,abhi,abhij,Abhijit,Abhijit,bh,bhi,bhij...etc and if you query for..bhi..then you should get the result as abhijit...

Comment: Maybe it is possible to play with FuzzySearch? But as I understand - it can replace any chars from requested terms, so if we got field `ab?de?2` and query `zbcdef2` - it can match them, but that's wrong... If it is possible to configure FuzzySearch to fire only on `?` from both sides (field and query) it may solve my problem. In general all my data had fixed lenght (15 chars), so I can replace all `*` with trailing `?` mark. How do you think?